# C#, need some help with changing form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

1. I would like som help to close form1 as you open form2.

   ```
   Form2 myForm = new Form2(); 
   myForm.Show();
   ```
2. I would like to know how to communicate between forms, like sending integers between?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms are just classes. When you say `Form2 myForm = new Form2();` you just create a new instance of a class. You communicate to an object (the instance of a class) by calling its methods, setting its properties or raising its events. No magic here.

In particular when you say `myForm.Show()`, *you have already communicated* to the other form. You just didn't realize it. It just so happened, that your Form2 class has had a method called Show, so it worked. But you can create your own methods and call them in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

```
form1.Close();
myForm.Show();
```

For second question -> forms are just objects. Learn OOP first, and concepts of class variables, properties, constructors etc... Then, use that to pass data between two objects (two forms)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could do that. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pass_data_between_forms.aspx), it lists 4 ways you could go about doing just that...

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 myForm = new Form2(this);
myForm.Show();
```

constructor Form2:

```
Window _parent;
void Form2(Window parent)
{
   _parent = parent;
}
```

and use _parent